# Policy Gradient training log-derivative un-normalized vs normalized objective

Tags: reinforcement-learning, ranking, policy-gradients

I am implementing a policy gradient training objective for optimizing ranking metrics in a learning-to-rank setting. For a given query $q$, a set of documents $D_q$ (retrieved from a first-stage ranker), a ranking policy $\pi_\theta$ is trained to maximize the following objective:

$ J(\theta) = \mathop{\mathbb{E}}_q \mathop{\mathbb{E}}_{y \sim \pi} \left[\sum_{d \in D_q}^{} U(y, rel)  \right] $.

where $U(y, rel)$ is the NDCG (or any ranking metric) with respect to the sampled ranking $y$ and ground-truth relevance $rel$. I intended to implement a policy-gradient method for training the policy with gradients computed using log-derivative trick, i.e.

$ \nabla J(\theta) = \mathop{\mathbb{E}}_q \nabla \mathop{\mathbb{E}}_{y \sim \pi} \left[\sum_{d \in D_q}^{} U(y, rel)  \right]$

using the log-derivative trick, it reduces to:

$\nabla J(\theta) = \mathop{\mathbb{E}}_q \mathop{\mathbb{E}}_{y \sim \pi} \nabla \pi \left[\sum_{d \in D_q}^{} U(y, rel)  \right]$.

Now in my implementation, I have replaced $ \mathop{\mathbb{E}}_q $ with a monte-carlo estimate, by sampling a random batch of queries and averaging over the inner quantity. But with the sample estimate of this: $\mathop{\mathbb{E}}_{y \sim \pi}$, I replaced it with a summation, instead of an average over the inner quantity.

Is this incorrect? I am getting results as expected, but I am afraid if my implementation if fundamentally wrong.